# How to add subdomain on Windows Server 2008 Standard?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, ip, vps, nameserver

I have two public IP. One is mapped to www.ezampal.com by a technician. I want to map subdomain.ezampal.com or www.subdomain.ezampal.com to another public IP. I'm using Windows VPS.

How to do that?

I mean I want to resolve the domain name. Sorry for newbie question, but I need help. I added Host A's. After adding them, do I need to contact registrar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a DNS record for the subdomain to your public DNS infrastructure.
2. Configure your web server to respond to that subdomain with the desired content.